# firebase, database, android studio: Not reading data from firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have data in database:
[database in firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUJV5.png)

I want read all child (Belgia, Czechy, Polska...) and display it in Text Field, but AFTER click the button (I don't change data in database).
The button have assigned below function:

```
public void f_btn_zaczytaj_dane(View view) {
    myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            TextView txt_opis_panstwa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_opis_panstwa);
            txt_opis_panstwa.setText(value);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

Befrore i write in code:

```
FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference myRef;

database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
myRef = database.getReference("kraj");
```

Unfortunately, when I press the button nothing happens.

I will be grateful for the help
Regards, Marcin

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through your children

```
public void f_btn_zaczytaj_dane(View view) {
    myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            TextView txt_opis_panstwa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_opis_panstwa);
            for (DataSnapshot country : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
             txt_opis_panstwa.append(country.getKey());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: When I fired this code, when I press the button in text field is still empty. As if the function "onDataChange" did not perform

Comment: post your logcat

Comment: Make sure the void is getting called, place a toast in the method to check

Comment: Yes, Toast is show when I click the button end execute function "f_btn_zaczytaj_dane"

Comment: Are the firebase database rules set to allow this?

Comment: for (DataSnapshot country : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    txt_opis_panstwa.append(country.getKey());
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ":: " + country.getKey(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

Comment: Try to set the firebase database rules to true

Comment: Internet permission?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

Comment: You are using the reference you posted before right?

Comment: Yes, I nothing change. FirebaseDatabase database;
DatabaseReference myRef;

database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
myRef = database.getReference("kraj");

Comment: I have runned out of ideas, all your connections with firebase work normally?

Comment: Connect your app to Firebase - green OK, Add the Realtime Database to your app - green ok. My app and database is visible in console firebase...

Comment: it's my first atempt

Comment: did you pasted the firebase configuration file?

Comment: My code is right, you must have some external problem with firebase. I am sorry i cant help you

Comment: I create new project, and I implements Yours method. Thats work. Problem must exist in my current project. I check this. Many thanx for help!

Comment: That is good. Glad to be helpful, please if it helped consider accepting the answer

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference krajRef = rootRef.child("flagiistolice").child("kraj");

public void f_btn_zaczytaj_dane(View view) {
    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            TextView txt_opis_panstwa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_opis_panstwa);
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String country = ds.getkey();
                txt_opis_panstwa.append(country);
                Log.d("TAG", country);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    };
    krajRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
}
```

Comment: Alex, but where is "f_btn_zaczytaj_dane" function?

Comment: Alex, I have problem in my current project. I check Yours solution in this week. Thanx for help.